# Cracked porcelain shower repair

Tags: shower

I live in Greece and have a very traditional house.I can't yet find a replacement porcelain shower tray the same dimensions. The original is cracked in several places but not leaking. I was thinking of covering it with a glue, a foundation and tiles or painting it with something that might stick??? Any ideas until I find a new one?
[image]Porcelain on concrete maybe Anyhow, very thick and heavy dimensions: 70cm wide x 65 deep x inside height 12 and outside 18.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is probably going to be opinion-based, but perhaps a picture or some more information would help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If it is cracked I suppose that it is porcelain (china) all the way through? Or is it porcelain on cast iron?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to try to upload a photo. It's definitely not cast iron. Porcelain on concrete maybe Anyhow, very thick and heavy dimensions: 70cm wide x 65 deep x inside height 12 and outside 18.

Comment: If you can't find a replacement you might pull out the broken one and replace it with tiles.

Comment: Thanks, I was starting to think that way, but have recently found a smaller square shower tray (not as nice as the old one) haven't installed it yet, but hope the issue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input. No it doesn't leak "yet". I've tried the repair kit which I had to get posted here indirectly as there are restrictions on liquids sent through the post to Greece. It chipped off again and doesn't work on hairline cracks. I do airbnb renting, so not so nice for guests to see it bodged up. I would like to find another but it's about 25 years old, so a bit vintage. I've just made a wooden palette to stand on (suggestion of a friend), so hope guests don't peak underneath.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does it leak? If not, why fix it?
2. You can look for a porcelain repair kit. I swear I saw one years ago. [Found some on  Amazon US](https://smile.amazon.com/s?k=porcelain+repair+kit&ref=nb_sb_noss_2). Surely you have an Amazon that can ship to you right?
3. Fill with white or clear silicone?
4. Would Amazon have a size you need?

No matter what fix you use, I believe you will still see a crack, but you will see a fixed crack.